# Access a Facebook Page from an External Facebook webpage app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm building a webpage Facebook app, I need the app to access a Facebook page and access and display user posts from the page. I have admin control of the Facebook page.

How should I go about achieving this: If I add my Facebook app webpage as a App on my Facebook page will it be able to access the information on the Facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to grant your application the "manage_pages" permission :
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?  client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token`
 once you have that permission you can make a request for an access token :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials
```

With this access token you can make requests to the graph api as your page...
You can [read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) on the authentication documentation.  Look for "App login" and "Page login"